# Getting several '20403 = No Object Found' errors while downloading photos from RMLS using phRETs

Tags: php, rets

I am trying to use phRETs to get photos from RMLS server (Matrix) using Media table for each photo UID. I am able to get photos for all sizes using my code, but when I try to run it against my DB for bulk updates (not huge, just few thousands) of photos, I am getting several '20403 = No Object Found' errors and hence not able to download the photo via nightly photo fetch job that we are trying to develop.

Is there any specific requirement or parameter that I must pass? I don't wan to use Property table here, but need to do it via Media table in order to avoid downloading already existing photos.

Any pointers/help here would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally found a workaround here.

We are still using Media table to get latest modified photos, but to fetch them from RMLS/Matrix server, we are using Property resource -

```
$rets->GetObject("Property", $photoType, $propertyId, $photoNum);
```

All the parameters such as $propertyId and $photoNum are already available in in Media  table, and we know all three photo types as well.

This has fixed our problem of getting  several '20403 = No Object Found' errors. Thought of adding it here so that it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the listings have been removed, sold, gone off market etc.

You should run a data update first syncing the listings and removing the one's that were removed. Then do your photo update.

Most RETS implementations will let you do a no limit query, something like `Query=(ID=0+,Status=|A)&Limit=None&Select=ID` that will return every active listing ID. Then you use that result to purge your deleted/off market listings. Then when you run your photo pull you'll get a more accurate update.

Comment: I did run update to sync the listings first. I am sure that the listings exist and they are active.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask why you are not using GetAllObjects() which librets has, but it doesn't look like phrets doesn't support that. Might be something to look at since they have PHP support too.